# Serializer get RelatedField

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

Below is code of my serializers.py and model.py class

**serializers.py**

```
class SliderImageSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=SliderImage
        fields='url','rank'

class ItemVariationsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # items = ItemsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ItemVariation
        fields ='price','item_code','image'

class RestaurantSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = ItemVariationsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    sliders = SliderImageSerializers(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model=Restaurant
        fields=('__all__')
```

**models.py**

```
class ItemVariation(models.Model):
    restaurant=models.ForeignKey(Restaurant,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item=models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0)
    item_code=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    keyword= models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='dishes/', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Below is response that i received

**response:**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "sliders": [
        {
            "url": "/media/restaurant/download_2.jpeg",
            "rank": 1
        }
    ],
    "name": "Haveli",
    "email": "test@tet.com",
    "web": "wdew",
    "short_description": "dsfsdf",
    "description": "fsdfsd",
    "phone": 21315,
    "lat": 30.704649,
    "lng": 76.717873,
    "address1": "dsff",
    "address2": "vfdg",
    "city": "sdfds",
    "state": "fs",
    "postalcode": "sdfsd",
    "avg_rating": 1,
    "price": 0,
    "restaurant_type": 1,
    "keywords": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
}
```

I need to add **ItemVariationsSerializer**  to **RestaurantSerializers** response

but i need response like below

> {
>       "id": 1,
>       "sliders": [
>           {
>               "url": "/media/restaurant/download_2.jpeg",
>               "rank": 1
>           }
>       ],
>       "name": "Haveli",
>       "email": "test@tet.com",
>       "items":[
>       {
>       "price":"213"
>       "item_code":"testr"
>       }
>       ]   
>       "keywords": [
>           1,
>           2,
>           3
>       ] }

I need your help to get needed response. Thanks

Comment: I think the problem could be `fields = ('__all__')` in `RestaurantSerializers`. What happens if you explicitly list all fields in that serializer, including the `items` field?

Comment: I tried  but i'm not getting and also many to many filed and ForeignKey are showing only id i need other field name